# playing two images in a loop when button is pressed using ontouchlistener in action_down state

Tags: android, eclipse, image, ontouchlistener, switching

I want two images to keep changing continuously while the button is pressed down using ontouchlistener in ACTION_DOWN state..

I am using image view to switch images.

Here is the code i want to implement it, i am also playing the sound in loop with which i want to play two images simultaneously when ACTION_DOWN

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Button zero = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    zero.setOnTouchListener(this);

    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound);

}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
{   

    switch (event.getAction()) 
    {

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    {
        mp.setLooping(true);
        mp.start();
    }

    break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    {
       mp.pause();
    }
    break;
}

return true;
}
```

}

Comment: SO what is the question?

Comment: The question is that i can set an image in ACTION_DOWN state giving it a static look. I need a method by which i could be able to continuously switch Two images which would give it a non static and animated look.                                             Any help would be HIGHLY appreciated.

Comment: So you just want to switch images in an imageview with some animation? Right?

Comment: Exactly. And let me show you my code where i want to implement it.

Comment: I cant find an ImageView referenced in your code?

Comment: Thats because i didnt really figure out yet that how will i repeat two images back to back when button is pressed in ACTION_DOWN

Answer (score 0):

Use the below function:

```
 public static void ImageViewAnimatedChange(Context c, final ImageView v, final Bitmap new_image) {
        final Animation anim_out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(c, android.R.anim.fade_out); 
        final Animation anim_in  = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(c, android.R.anim.fade_in); 
        anim_out.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener()
        {
            @Override public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}
            @Override public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
            @Override public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
            {
                v.setImageBitmap(new_image); 
                anim_in.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
                    @Override public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}
                    @Override public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
                    @Override public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {}
                });
                v.startAnimation(anim_in);
            }
        });
        v.startAnimation(anim_out);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for alot of effort you are putting up for me bro. Just a little thing, i cant figure out how to pressing a button with ontouchlistener can this code get along, i dont really know how to connect these both things.

Comment: You just call the function where you need to change the image, that is in your onClick listener of zero button. Your onTouch Listener needs major changes as the cases are not proper: `break;` should come inside those curly braces. Just call the function depending on your case pass the `context`, the `imageView` and your `bitmap`

Comment: Also you should consider changing your onTouch listener to an onClick listener, `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` will be executed as soon as the user lifts her finger. So that is of no use to you.

Comment: A huge favor man, i would love you for this, Please if you could write me code for playing two images when the button is pressed and stops when the finger is up, following up with the sound clip playing in the loop, which works the same as the images, stops when the finger is up.                        I really tried to do it but i am going nutts :/